# Cocoa equivalent of AppleScript 'tell application'

Tags: cocoa, applescript

In AppleScript I can simply run

```
tell application "Spotify" to playpause
```

and Spotify is magically paused. But can I do that in Cocoa? I'm talking built-in Cocoa methods. Even though I could just run the AppleScript file, there has to be a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).